# Generate xml from XElement foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have two XDocuments which I transform into XElement.

From these two XElement I have to filter one element and merge them. and to make them I use a foreach loop like below:

```cs
var xelPerson = xDocument1.Root;
var xelCity = XDocument2.Root;

XElement xmlFinal = new XElement("Root");

foreach (var rowXel2 in xelCity.Elements("City"))
{
    var idPersonCity = rowXel2.Element("idPerson").Value;

    XElement rowPerson = xelPerson.Elements("Person")
        .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Element("idPerson").Value == idPersonCity);

    xmlFinal.Add(rowPratica);
    xmlFinal.Add(rowXML);
}
xmlFinal.Save(@"c:\temp\final.xml");
```

I have as final result this xml:

```xml
<Root>
  <Person>
   <idPerson>1</idPerson>
   <name>Luke</name>
  </Person>
  <City>
    <idPerson>1</idPerson>
    <cityPerson>London</cityPeson>
  </City>
  <Person>
    <idPerson>2</idPerson>
    <name>Maria</name>
  </Person>
  <City>
    <idPerson>2</idPerson>
    <cityPerson>Paris</cityPeson>
  </City>
</Root>
```

I would need to have as result the following xml:

```xml
<Root>
  <Person>
   <idPerson>1</idPerson>
   <name>Luke</name>
  </Person>
  <City>
    <idPerson>1</idPerson>
    <cityPerson>London</cityPeson>
  </City>
</Root>
<Root>
  <Person>
    <idPerson>2</idPerson>
    <name>Maria</name>
  </Person>
  <City>
    <idPerson>2</idPerson>
    <cityPerson>Paris</cityPeson>
  </City>
</Root>
```

is't possible to fix the loop so that the root tag is added every time?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML needs a single root.  If you want to enclose the repeated elements in a container element (named `Root` or anything else), you need to create the container element instances *within* the loop and add them to an outer-most root, then save the outer-most, like this:

```
XElement outerMost = new XElement("ActualRoot");

foreach (var rowXel2 in xelCity.Elements("City"))
{
    XElement xmlFinal = new XElement("Root");
    var idPersonCity = rowXel2.Element("idPerson").Value;

    XElement rowPerson = xelPerson.Elements("Person").FirstOrDefault(r => r.Element("idPerson").Value == idPersonCity);

    xmlFinal.Add(rowPratica);
    xmlFinal.Add(rowXML);
    outerMost.Add(xmlFinal);
}

outerMost.Save(@"c:\temp\final.xml");
```

Comment: I've already tried this and I only get one result while I have several to display. Thank you

Comment: thanks but then is't possible to delete the ActualRoot tag before saving?

Comment: Well you could, but then it wouldn't be valid XML.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element

Comment: yes that's true, but can't we avoid the ActualRoot tag?

Comment: You can call it whatever you want.  But you can't add multiple elements to nothing.  You need exactly one root.